# Background all day event missing in FullCalendar

Tags: jquery, json, fullcalendar

I have a problem with a new Full Calendar problem of mine. I retrieve my events through an AJAX call, and the JSON response is included below.

[image]

As you can see the response as a start date of August 6 and an end date of August 8, but when you look at the calendar output, it only shows August 6 and August 7.

[image]

Where can I go from here?

Comment: Hi, can you make this runnable ?

Comment: This is the expected behaviour. Event end dates are _exclusive_ (as per the documentation) and for all-day events, the time component is ignored.